# OSX Toolbar for Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, toolbar

What do i need to install, and what settings do i need to change to have the magnify toolbar thing that OSX has in Ubuntu 9.04?

My system is running Compiz and is able to do all of the frilly UI "wow" things like cube, wobble window, etc, without any lag, so machine horsepower shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of [Gnome-Do](http://do.davebsd.com/) have this as well. It is called [Docky](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/index.php?title=Docky), I use it on my machine and I love it. Gnome-Do's Docky feature is pretty simple, something like awn provides some more features and fancy looks more in line with OS X Leopard's dock.

Comment: Perfect! I already use Gnome-do, and did not know of the Docky feature that is built in. I'll give it a try tonight and mark your answer as correct if it works as you describe.

Comment: Also, Jaunty has Gnome-Do in its repositories, but you might want to install from the ppa (http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Installing_Do#9.04_.28Jaunty.29), there are some nice new features in the newest version. I just installed it and I'm liking it so far.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for a dock. Cairo is one of the most popular for Ubuntu, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CairoDock) should get you up and running!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [Avant Window Navigator (awn)](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-avant-window-navigator-awn-in-ubuntu-710-gutsy-gibbon.html) - the link has instructions for gutsy, but they should apply equally to new distributions as well!